# Reduce operation on Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, reduce

I am trying to reduce an RDD with 3 values, so, at first, i map the rdd with the following format

```
a = mytable.rdd.map(lambda w: (w.id,(w.v1,w.v2,w.v3)))
```

and then in the next step i reduce it with the following code

```
b = a.reduceByKey(lambda a,b,c: (a[0] +','+ a[1],b[0] +','+ b[1],c[0] +','+ c[1]))
```

However, i get an error which is:
TypeError: () takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

My goal is to add all the values of that rdd, so for example if my rdd having these values:

```
[(id1, ('a','b','c')),(id1', ('e','f','g'))]
```

After reduce i want the results to be in this order:

```
[(id1, ('a,d','b,e','c,f'))]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimal solution can be expressed as:

```
a.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda vs: [",".join(v) for v in  zip(*vs)])
```

where initial `groupByKey` groups data into a structure equivalent to:

```
('id1', [('a','b','c'), ('e','f','g')])
```

`zip(*vs)` transposes values to:

```
[('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'g')]
```

and comprehension with `join` concatenates each tuple.

`reduceByKey` is really not the right choice (think about complexity) here but in general it takes a function of two arguments so `lambda a, b, c: ...` is wont' do. I believe you wanted something like this:

```
lambda a, b: (a[0] + "," + b[0], a[1] + "," + b[1], a[2] + "," + b[2])
```